# LIBGDX - Error creating music

Tags: java, audio, libgdx

I'm attempting to simply load a Music asset using libgdx, and this is what I have:

```
Music main_background;
main_background = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("data/music/main_bg.wav"));
```

This code is exactly the same code as they have in the small tutorial of "Making a game" with libgdx, and I'm trying to load my own sound that I have made (Using GarageBand, in case that matters). Whenever I try running this as a Desktop application, I get a bunch of errors:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error creating music com.badlogic.gdx.backends.openal.Wav$Music for file: data/music/main_bg.wav
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error reading WAV file: data/music/main_bg.wav
>
> Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: RIFF header not found: data/music/main_bg.wav

I'm not sure what the problem could be, because the audio file isn't corrupt (because I can listen to it perfectly fine) yet I can't find information anywhere about people getting this type of error when loading an asset.

I have a bunch of Texture's loaded just fine, but for some unknown reason I can't load a Music asset (and for the record, I tried loading the same file as a Sound asset and get essentially the same error).

Has anyone come across this before or have any ideas on what could be wrong?

EDIT: I should mention I also get this error if I try loading an mp3 or ogg file as well, it doesn't just happen with a wav

Comment: Are there any other GDX log messages in the console?  Maybe something about OpenAL?  Also, what platform is your desktop?  Do you get a different error if the file doesn't exist at all (e.g., like "data/music/gibberish.wav")

Comment: I just tried to run my small game including the music today, and now it worked. I'm unsure what the problem was still, because I didn't change anything at all (I didn't even close and reopen Eclispe), and I had refreshed the asset directory multiple times because I thought it didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, know the differences between Sound and Music in libGdx.
Read this: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Audio
The problem maybe is in bit rate.
I had this problem and I changed the bitrate of wav files to 705kbps and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to `.ogg`, it occupies less space. And keep it in your data folder.
Then declare a variable named `music`:

```
Music music;
```

After that in your `create` method:

```
music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("data/whoo.ogg"));
```

Then use it anywhere in your game - in `render`, `touchUp` `touchDown` anywhere you want the music:

```
music.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was solved by restarting Eclipse. It seems some SDK files had not fully installed yet and restarting Eclipse allowed them to complete the install.